# How do I create Google Web App that can create new Google Doc, then open it in browser tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have written a script that creates a new google Doc (a lyric sheet template). Now, I want to insert that script into a Google Web App script that I can attach to a button on a (new) Google Site. When the user clicks that button (called something like "New Song"), the new song template is created and then opened in a browser tab, ready to be modified as a new song. I can't figure out how to make a Web App do anything except open an existing Google doc or sheet, etc. In other words, the "doGet" command never runs the HTML code to create the new Google lyric doc. My working code for the create lyric doc is as follows:

Part II:
I reworked the code I referenced in the comments below and I can create and open a new lyric Doc, but I can't get the formatting part of the script to work (as noted below).

```
 function createNewLandscapeSong() {
   var doc = DocumentApp.create('Rename with song title');
   var title = "replace with song title"
   var url = doc.getUrl();
   var body = doc.getBody();
   var paragraph = body.insertParagraph(0, "");
   var text1 = paragraph.appendText("© replace with writer(s)");
  text1.setFontSize(8);
   var rowsData = [['PUT FIRST VERSE/CHORUS HERE.', 'PUT SECOND VERSE/NEXT CHORUS/BRIDGE/ETC HERE.']];
    var style = {};
   body.insertParagraph(0, title)
       .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
   table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
   style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = 0;
   table.setAttributes(style);
 }
```

Part II Code:

```
 function doGet(e){

  // create the doc
  var doc = createDoc()

  // save the doc to Drive
  var driveFile = DriveApp.createFile(doc).setName("New Lyric");

  // tell the user how to access it
  var fileURL = driveFile.getUrl();
  var fileName = driveFile.getName();

  var HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p>You made a new lyric doc.</p>"
  + "<p> You can access it here: "
  + '<a target="blank" href="' + fileURL + '">' + fileName + '</a></p>');
  return HTMLOutput
 }

  function createDoc() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Rename with song title');
  // Code below not working
  var title = "replace with song title and then link this text to song title cell in Catalog Spreadsheet"
  var id = doc.getId();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragraph = body.insertParagraph(0, "");
  var text1 = paragraph.appendText("© replace with writer(s)");
text1.setFontSize(8);
  var rowsData = [['PUT FIRST VERSE/CHORUS HERE.  (SUGGEST USE ALL CAPS.)', 'PUT SECOND VERSE/NEXT CHORUS/BRIDGE/ETC HERE.']];
  var style = {};
      body.insertParagraph(0, title)
     .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
      table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
      style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = 0;
      table.setAttributes(style);
  // End of code section not working
  return doc
 }
```

Comment: Where is your `doGet()` and html code?

Comment: I did not include as it is standard, but meanwhile, I think I got some insight into how to make this happen (from: http://googleappscripting.com/doget-dopost-tutorial-examples/ -- specifically, the section on that page entitled "Dynamic Web Pages with the HTML Service"). I'm gonna work with that awhile and if I get this figured out, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `doGet()` only runs when you initially open up the Web App in your browser. Any additional calls to the server-side script have to be done with [client-to-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).
2. It may be easier to [extract your HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) from your server-side script. This will help you write code in the web page HTML to make calls to your server-side function.

So you will have **2 separate files**: Code.gs and Index.html.

Code.gs

```
/*
  This function simply returns the html we've created to the client for display.
*/
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}


/*
The scripts below this line are to alow the client-side scripts from the Index.html page call and get information from the server-side script.
*/

function createNewLandscapeSong() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Rename with song title');
  var title = "replace with song title"
  var url = doc.getUrl();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragraph = body.insertParagraph(0, "");
  var text1 = paragraph.appendText("© replace with writer(s)");
  text1.setFontSize(8);
  var rowsData = [['PUT FIRST VERSE/CHORUS HERE.', 'PUT SECOND VERSE/NEXT CHORUS/BRIDGE/ETC HERE.']];
  var style = {};
  body.insertParagraph(0, title)
  .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
  table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = 0;
  table.setAttributes(style);

  return {
    url: url,
    title: title
  };
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Make Doc"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(openNewDoc)
          .createNewLandscapeSong()" />
    <script>
       function openNewDoc(results){
           window.open(results.url, '_blank').focus();
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So the webpage makes a call to the server-side code to make a document and retrieve it's url. We then use that url to open that document in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

user clicks that button 
you put an event listener to the button then trigger a function that opens the file

```
  in the HTML - the BUTTON
   <div>                   
     <div id="submit">OPEN THE FILE IN A NEW TAB</div> 
   </div>
 in the SCRIPT of the HTML
 <script>
  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",openFile)
  function openFile() {
    window.open('url');
    google.script.run.createNewLandscapeSong();  
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You say "event listener": is that in the form of a web app attached to the button? Doesn't that require a doGet? In other words, not sure what to do, where to put your suggested code.

Comment: Chris W: You rock. Flawless. I'm learning, but it's an uphill slog for an amateur at this. Now, any ideas how I can produce a dialog box (where you put the button "Make Doc") that asks songwriter for the name of the new song and then inputs that to the Google Doc when the "Make Doc" button is clicked so I can jettison the "Rename with song title" and "replace with song title" bits?